# UWP - binding multiple grid views to a list of lists

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm a little confused on how to accomplish this. Here is the situation. I have a collection of objects themselves have a collection of objects.  I want to create a new grid view for every object in the first collection that would use the collection from the second object as its source.

For example. In my view model I have something like this

```
public ObservableCollection<ApiResponse> NewsStories
```

where ApiResponse is defined as something like

```
public class ApiResponse
{
    public List<Article> Articles { get; set; }
}
```

My xaml before I made this a list of lists was something like

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Articles}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GridViewTemplate }"
        IsItemClickEnabled="False"
        IsSwipeEnabled="False"
        CanDragItems="False"
        SelectionMode="Single"
        />
```

I was able to bind to just a single api response and see the grid view display all the articles from that response. But now that I'm going to have a list of lists I'm not really sure how to proceed.  I tried enclosing this in a list view, to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I might have figured it out. First in my xaml I have something like

```
<GridView
        ItemsSource="{Binding NewsStories}"
        IsItemClickEnabled="False"
        CanDragItems="False"
        SelectionMode="None"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ImageTextTemplate }">
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    </GridView>
```

And in my page resources then I have

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ArticleTemplate"  x:DataType="data:Article">           
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="180" Height="240" >
             <!-- stuff here -->
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>

    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ImageTextTemplate" x:DataType="data:ApiResponse">          
            <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Articles}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ArticleTemplate}"                    
                Header="{Binding Source}" />
    </DataTemplate>

</Page.Resources>
```